# In an ordered array, is it generally faster to find out an item is not in the array than to find out it is?

Tags: arrays, sorting

In an ordered array, is it generally faster to find out an item is not in the array than to find out it is?

Our teacher asked this question, mostly we said no but he said the answer is yes, it is faster. I really got no clue whatsoever how come even that is possible. After all, to find out that the item is not in the array we must make the most comparisons but if it is in the array we will possibly find it before that.

Can anybody explain? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following construction: Let's define a **target area** inside the array which contains the places where the element in question could be. When the search algorithm starts, the target area is the whole array because we have not looked at anything in the array yet.

Now suppose you do a binary search (which would be most appropriate for ordered arrays). You would look at the element in the middle of the array. If that element is smaller than the element you're looking for, you know that the element you're looking for must be on its right. Therefore the target area has been reduced to the right half of the array. Same in the opposite case: If the element you looked at was bigger, then the new target area is the left half of the array.

As you see, every step of the search algorithm will reduce the target area in some way, so that you get closer and closer to your answer. That holds true for each search algorithm. For example, if you were to iterate linearly through the elements, you would be reducing the target area by one element in each step.

Regardless of whether you're checking for inclusion (whether the item is in the array) or exclusion (whether it's not in the array), your algorithm stops at one of two situations:

1. While trying to narrow down the search area, you happen to pick an element from the array that is just the item that you were looking for. At this point, the inclusion test would return `true`, or the exclusion test would return `false`.
2. The target area is exhausted (i.e., reduced to an empty set). In this case, inclusion yields `false`, exclusion yields `true`.

From this reasoning follows that the inclusion and exclusion test are entirely symmetrical, therefore I agree with your "no". But please, do ask your teacher to explain his reasoning and post it here.